# Guessing a general form for a recursive sequence

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

For a proof by induction exercise, I'm given a sequence defined recursively as $s_0 = 0, s_1 = 1, s_2 = 0; s_n := s_{n-3} + s_{n-2} - s_{n-1}$ for $n \geq 3$ and I am asked to make a guess for the general form of $s_n$. However, I'm struggling to come up with the general form, as from what I've calculated, the sequence simply goes back and forth between $0$ and $1$. I've tried a few guesses with floor functions and even a sine function, but they all don't seem to work or is not what the exercise expects me to prove.

So could I ask for some guidance in finding the general form? If I have the general form I'm pretty confident that I can use induction to prove it so I don't really want the proof, only the general form. Thanks!

Comment: Since $(s_2,s_3,s_4)=(s_0,s_1,s_2)$ the sequence is periodic, as you have remarked.  If you are worried about it, just prove inductively that $s_{2n}=0, s_{2n+1}=1$.

Comment: Is there no way to have $s_n$ equal something and then prove it in one go (probably through strong induction), or do I really have to break it into odd and even cases?

Comment: As a general method, for linear recursions one starts with the characteristic polynomial, which in this case is $x^3+x^2-x-1=(x+1)^2(x-1)$  so the general solution is of the form $a_n=A(-1)^n+B(1)^n+Cn(-1)^n$  You can then use the initial conditions to find $A.B,C$.

Comment: To be sure:  I'm not entirely clear on what you are asking.  As I mentioned, since the recursion has "depth $3$", showing that you get the same triple twice proves it is periodic.  Nor is parity a difficult or unusual thing to consider.   Look at what I said about the general method, maybe that's what you want.  But keep in mind that, in most degree $3$ cases, the cubic is difficult to factor.

Comment: The general method that you had described is pretty much exactly what I was looking for, although I didn't know about the process with characteristic polynomials as I hadn't learnt it in my lectures yet.

Comment: This general method works well for depth $2$ recursions (like the Fibonacci recursion) but it's not so great beyond that...as the polynomials become difficult to factor.   Still, it is a very powerful method and well worth learning.  [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Characteristic_polynomial) is a good place to read about the method.